# How to configure a second navigation property from owned types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following setup

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<CarRecord> Owns {get; set;}
    public virtual List<CarRecord> Drives {get; set;}
}

public class CarRecord
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual Person Owner {get; set;}
    public int OwnerId {get; set;}
    
    public virtual Person Driver {get; set;}
    public int DriverId {get; set;}
}
```

I tried to configure the navigation in two ways, as:

```
builder.OwnsMany(x => x.Owns, x =>
{          
    x.HasOne(x => x.Driver)
    .WithMany(x => x.Drives)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DriverId);
});
```

This throws the error: `The navigation 'Person.Drives' is not supported because it is pointing to an owned entity type 'CarRecord'. Only the ownership navigation from the entity type 'Person' can point to the owned entity type.`

```
builder.OwnsMany(x => x.Owns);

builder
    .HasMany(x => x.Drives)
    .WithOne(x => x.DriverId);
```

And this throws the error:  `The entity type 'CarRecord' cannot be configured as non-owned because it has already been configured as a owned.`

What is the correct way of configuring this navigation so I can point to two different Person instances from CarRecord object?

Comment: You can use `InverseProperty`.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar This seems to be the correct answer, do you want to post this?